# How to use the count() function in XSL - trying to count the amount of "A"s there are in a report

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to count the amount of `A`'s there are in a school report.

Here is the report:

```
<class>
  <student>
    <first-name>Jane</first-name>
    <last-name>Doe</last-name>
    <grade>A</grade>
  </student>
  <student>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <grade>B</grade>
  </student>
  <student>
    <first-name>Harry</first-name>
    <last-name>Grandson</last-name>
    <grade>A</grade>
  </student>
  <student>
    <first-name>Lacy</first-name>
    <last-name>Jones</last-name>
    <grade>C</grade>
  </student>
</class>
```

How do I get the number of `A`'s in the report?

I came up with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/class/student/grade)"/>
```

But that counts everything - So I tried to get only the `A`'s with this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/class/student/grade/A)"/>
```

But this doesn't work either.

I also tried this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/class/student[grade=A])"/>
```

But that doesn't work either - what is the problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/class/student[grade='A'])"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
count(/class/student/grade[text()="A"])
```

Comment: please provide a complete answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.